# Can we use external hard disk as Internal

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

My internal hard-disk is giving an error, while I am starting my Laptop, as hard-disk not found. I want to install an operating system in my external hard-disk and use it to start my laptop. Is it possible or the only option which I have is to buy a new internal hard-disk ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your external hard drive as replacement of your internal hard drive. What that means, you can disassemble your hard drive enclosure and take out the hard drive, then install it in your laptop as a replacement of the faulty one.

So, you only need to know what type of external hard drive do you have ? is it 3.5" or 2.5" ..etc. if is it 3.5", then you won't be able to do the above method since 3.5" can't be installed on a laptop due to the hard drive physical size dimensions. (2.5" is the standard physical size dimension for laptops internal hard drives.).

*NOTE: usually, 3.5" external drives has a power supply (charger) that won't turn on unless it's plugged into the wall, while 2.5" or smaller drives don't.*

If you don't want to go through all that and you need to boot from your external drive instead. You can make a USB bootable Windows using a third-party tool like [WinToUSB](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) is doable solution, but not permanent.

Comment: Hi iSR5, Yes I want to boot the external drive and connect it with laptop via USB and then use it. Is that possible ?

Comment: @AnubhavMishra yes it's possible, as I stated in the last paragraph of my answer, you need to use a third-party tool like WinToUSB to make a portable Windows that can be booted from an external hard drive.